# Suppose $V$ and $V/W$ is Banach space, then is $W$ closed subspace of $V$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space.
I know $W$ is closed, then $V/W$ is Banach space, but what about other direction?
Suppose $V/W$ is Banach space, then is $W$ closed subspace of $V$? I would like to know the proof of this.

Reference(websites) are also appreciated. Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $W$ is not a closed subspace of $V$, then the quotient $V/W$ is not even a normed vector space.

Assume $W$ is not closed and $x \in \overline{W} \setminus W$. Then the norm of the coset $-x+W$ is
$$
\| -x+W \| = \inf_{w \in W} \| -x +w \| = 0,
$$
while $-x+W$ is not the zero coset in $V/W$.

Comment: Alternatively, use $W = \ker(V \to V/W)$. The kernel of a continuous linear map between normed spaces is closed.

Comment: Aha, good point. I was going to suggest writing a separate short answer, but I see you already did.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Michal Miskiewicz said, if $W$ is not closed and you take the linear quotient $V/W$ with the quotient topology, it's not a topological vector space - because the set $\{0\} \subset V/W$ is not closed - its preimage under the quotient map is $W$ - which is not closed in $V$.  In a topological vector space, every singleton set must be closed (at least according to the defintion in Rudin.)